# How can I get xticks to have a monthly interval instead of daily on my matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

I have a dataframe with the index as datetime.
There are duplicate indices. Here is the `df.head()`

```
                  Landing         Date           Boat    Trip Type  Anglers ... Albacore    Barracuda   Total Caught
Date                                                                                    
2020-01-01  daveys-locker   2020-01-01      Freelance      3/4 Day       55 ...        0            0            223
2020-01-01  daveys-locker   2020-01-01  Western Pride   1/2 Day PM       38 ...        0            0            137
2020-01-02  daveys-locker   2020-01-02      Freelance      3/4 Day       75 ...        0            0            185
2020-01-02  daveys-locker   2020-01-02  Western Pride   1/2 Day PM       38 ...        0            0            144
2020-01-03  daveys-locker   2020-01-03      Freelance      3/4 Day       77 ...        0            0            395
```

I've tried a few ways to get the `xticks` not to show every day or every index (can't even tell because there are so many). Here was my original.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,25))
chart = sbn.scatterplot(x='Date',y='Total Caught',data=daveysdf_2019, hue='Boat', style='Trip Type',s=150)
ax.set_title('Daveys Locker 2019 Totals')
ax.legend(framealpha=0.5)
chart.set_xticklabels(labels=daveysdf_2019.Date.unique(),rotation=75)
figure = chart.get_figure()
```

[image]

I tried using `set_major_locator` with `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator` and `formatter` but that wound up not showing any `xticks`

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,25))
chart = sbn.scatterplot(x='Date',y='Total Caught',data=daveysdf_2019, hue='Boat', style='Trip Type',s=150)
ax.set_title('Daveys Locker 2019 Totals')
ax.legend(framealpha=0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
chart.set_xticklabels(labels=daveysdf_2019.Date.unique(),rotation=75)
```

[image]

I also tried something else that I can't remember and it made the `xtick` interval spaced out but only from the first date up through mid Feb.

Edit:
After converting the Date column to datetime here is what the new graph looks like. If I use set_major_locator/formatter the points are on the right but the xticks are reset to every day and overlapping.

[image]

Comment: can you share the data set?

Comment: Your dates are coming in as strings.  If you want to use locators or formatters, you need to convert to dates.

Comment: AdhunThalekkara Here is the file. FYI this does not have the index as dates yet. I did that in code after reading in. https://github.com/Sirly/FishingReports/blob/master/cleanData-daveys.csv


@JodyKlymak You are correct. I had converted it to datetime before but saved to csv after cleaning up formatting. Now the graph xtick is in Years from 2000-2020 with all points shoved into the right side. Will edit comment to add image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is correct:

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,25))
chart = sbn.scatterplot(x='Date',y='Total Caught',data=daveysdf_2019, hue='Boat', style='Trip Type',s=150)
ax.set_title('Daveys Locker 2019 Totals')
ax.legend(framealpha=0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
chart.set_xticklabels(labels=daveysdf_2019.Date.unique(),rotation=75)
```

But you need to add one line at the end of this code to avoid matplotlib not show any ticks, you need to set `xlim` of the axis with:

```
ax.set_xlim([daveysdf_2019['Date'].iloc[0], daveysdf_2019['Date'].iloc[-1]])
```

Comment: Adding your solution along with @JodyKlymak's type conversion fixed it. Whew! Thanks everyone!